# Javap equalant in node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to know is their any thing in node.js to find available no. of methods in node module's js file like in java we have Javap to know the method available in the java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for finding all global variables 
`for (var k in global) { 
if(typeof k =='function')
console.log(k); 
}`

but from a specific node modules either you have to read their Documentation or use some of the popular IDE which indexes the node_modules